# 'open' modifier conflicts with the extension's default access of 'public'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a highly-customisable component, a framework, to implement in my future game development projects; a joystick.

The joystick should appear when the user touches the screen, the internal knob moves around as the touches change, and it finally disappears when touches end.

Writing a component that responds to this behaviour is not too much of a problem; what I would like to do, however, is delegate away as much "raw" control as possible from the user and implement methods that respond to touches without having to manually override the `UIResponder` `touchesBegan` etc. methods.

What I have done works, so far: I have extended the `SKScene` with a public extension within the framework which overrides the `touches` methods and calls the static methods that update the joystick position in the screen depending on the current touches and events.

There is just a little nuance I'm trying to solve; here is my code:

```swift
public extension SKScene {
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        Joystick.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

XCode wants the `touchesBegan` method to necessarily have the `open` modifier, but the least restrictive modifier the extension can take is `public`; XCode spits out a warning that says:

> 'open' modifier conflicts with the extension's default access of 'public'

Is there any way to solve this issue? Is my implementation to be considered bad design, and if so, is there another way to achieve this result without having the user to manually implement and override the `touches` methods? Thank you.

Comment: why not just make your extension an open extension (basically remove public)

Comment: btw,  this seems a little too insane.  You should be making Joystick its own node with `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`  You can even make an SKS dedicated to your joystick, so that when you are using your framework, you just load in the SKS file

Comment: Extensions without a modifier specified are declared as internal; if I were to declare it as open, Xcode complains as it only applies to classes.

Comment: Extensions without a modifier take on the class properties,  which means skscene is internal or public, which means the members inside of it are internal.  If you took out all modifiers, what happens?

Comment: The reason why this is bad is because if you place this in a framework, you lose the ability to have touch interaction outside of the joystick unless you subclass SKScene to override it again.

Comment: It means that since SKScene is an open class, extending it would also inherit the open modifier; didn't know that. Thank you.